# ng-repeat condition filter with two expressions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am looking in a way to have one ng-repeat that filter on or 'the order' or on 'the id'. 
So something like this:

```
ng-repeat "cd in cds | filter: !order ? orderBy:'id' : orderBy:'order'"
```

So if the order is empty (does not have data) it should order by the id, if the order does have data it should order by 'order'. Is this possible? It now gives two times the same data out, the condition does not seem to work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621425/angularjs-filter-expression-in-ng-repeat

Comment: Easier solution posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close; try something like this:

```
ng-repeat "cd in cds | orderBy: (!order ? 'id' : 'order')"
```

Comment: interesting solution indeed, thanks. Somehow did not get the !order to work had to make a $scope in the controller. Show you in the answer how i got it to work

Answer (score 1):

thank you Andrew Diamond, this became the ng-repeat for me

```
ng-repeat="cd in cds| orderBy: (ordering != null ? 'order' : 'id')"
```

and this the controller (had to add the $scope.ordering):

```
    function GetCDS() {
        $http({
            method: 'Get',
            url: "/cds"
        })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {        
                $scope.cds = data;
                $scope.ordering = data[0].order;
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error';
            });
    }
```